# Calling a Sub within a Form

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a Form set in place within my workbook. This form contains a button. On the click of the button, I would like to call a Sub which is located within the "ThisWorkbook" section. How could I go along of doing this?

Button within form...

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Main("Test")
End Sub
```

The Sub that needs to be called within "ThisWorkbook"

```
Sub Main(DPass As String)
    msgbox Dpass
End Sub
```

This will give me a compile error of: `Sub or Function not defined`. Why does this happen?

Comment: Prefix thisworkbook before your sub name.  Call ThisWorkbook.Main()

Comment: ^^ but using `Call ThisWorkbook.Main("Test")` or, more simply, `ThisWorkbook.Main "Test"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are essentially two types of modules:

- "Standard/Procedural" modules
- Class modules

"Document" modules (e.g. `ThisWorkbook`, `Sheet1`, etc.) are just special kinds of class modules. Same for "UserForm" modules, which are basically classes with a default instance and a designer.

Members of a class module don't exist at run-time; a class is nothing but a *blueprint* for an *object* - so you need to either create an object of that type (the class determines the type), or use an existing one.

`ThisWorkbook` is an *instance* of the `Workbook` class; `Sheet1` is an instance of the `Worksheet` class. `Chart1` is an instance of the `Chart` class; `UserForm1` is an *instance* of the `UserForm` class. And so on.

If you make a new class module and call it `Class1`, and add a public procedure to it:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    MsgBox "Something!"
End Sub
```

Then in order to call `DoSomething` you need an *instance* of `Class1`:

```
Dim foo As Class1
Set foo = New Class1
foo.DoSomething
```

If `DoSomething` is in the `ThisWorkbook` module, then you can call it by qualifying the method name with the object it exists on, as was mentioned in the comments and in the other answer:

```
ThisWorkbook.DoSomething
```

---

If `DoSomething` is implemented in a *standard/procedural module*, then there is no object, the procedure exists in global scope, and you can just do this:

```
DoSomething
```

However public members of procedural modules are also exposed as *macros* (`Public Sub`) and *user-defined functions* (`Public Function`), which you may not want to do.

If you need a procedural module with public members that you can only call from VBA code (and not by clicking a button on a worksheet, or by entering a formula in a cell), then you can specify `Option Private Module` at the top:

```
Option Private Module

Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' DoSomething is not exposed as a macro, 
    ' but can be called from anywhere in the VBA project.
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice answer with detail. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the depth, as now I have a really good understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Put your sub in a module and not in your ThisWorkbook unless you have to for some reason, if so use `ThisWorkbook.Main "string"`.

Comment: It should be either `Call ThisWorkbook.Main("Test")` or `ThisWorkbook.Main "Test"` - putting the brackets around the parameters for a subroutine invoked as `subname(parameters)` is a dangerous habit to get into - e.g. if two parameters were required then using a syntax of `subname(parm1,parm2)` would fail.  It often works when only a single parameter is needed, but will then sometimes give unexpected results (due to the brackets forcing the parameter to be passed as `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`).